# Does win32api.GetKeyState() reset to 0?

Tags: python, winapi, input, user-input

I'm trying to make a keyboard "piano" in python, and for input I'm using win32api.GetKeyState.

```
import win32api
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()

a1 = mixer.Sound('wav/a1.wav')

while True:
    qIn = win32api.GetKeyState(0x51)
    if qIn == 1:
        a1.play(0)
```

`win32api.GetKeyState(0x51)` -- Gets state of "q" key. When "q" is down, value is 1. Else, value is 0.
Instead of playing "a1" one time, it plays it on repeat until Q is pressed again.
 This brings me back to the title, does `win32api.GetKeyState()` reset back to 0? Or is there another issue with the code?

I've also tried resetting it manually, with the same result:

```
while True:
    qIn = win32api.GetKeyState(0x51)
    if qIn == 1:
        a1.play(0)
        qIn = 0
```

Sorry if this might be obvious, but I can't find anything online that says it does/doesn't.

Comment: [`GetKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate): *"The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue."* The code doesn't seem to be reading any messages from the thread's message queue.

Comment: You need to use [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) insted